# Jest unit test use destructuring assignment about 'import'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, antd

The file I want to test import ant design and code use destructuring assignment like below.

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
const { Option } = Select;
```

When I run jest unit test, it show below error.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Select is not defined

    > 16 | const { Option } = Select;
         |                    ^
```

But when i use `select.option` directly, test can run fun.

what do i do can made test fun and no need change test code.

-----update-----

I got strange conclusion. when I use node directly(`node ./node_module/.bin/jest --watchAll`), it's all right. But when i use npm script to run it(`"jest": "jest --watchAll"`) will have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The component names are case-sensitive. `Select` not `select` is the correct spelling.

Try:

```js
import { Select } from 'antd';
const { Option } = Select;
```

Comment: Sorry, my code is right spelling, it's just error for spell in this question. I means the correct spell also got error.